# How to cope with a Narcissist?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

What techniques can you use to cope with a Narcissist on the team who is very close to the General Manager and we suspect is always passing mistruths upwards that reflect badly on the rest of the team? The reason we suspect he is doing this is that the Manager asks the weirdest questions, right out of left-field after he is seen talking with him, which he never did before the Narcissist joined us. The Narcissist seems to be less competent than the rest of us, but his opinion of himself is the opposite.

Comment: I don't see how this can be answered usefully in its current form, unfortunately - it's too general.  How you deal with someone is you deal with the specific issues that come up - there's not a general "game plan" for dealing with a generic narcissistic person.

Comment: @Joe I disagree. Narcissism has specific traits. Also there is specific behavior they are showing (trying to whisper mis-truths in the managers ear). I think some suitable and useful answers will possible.

Comment: I agree with Joe that this question is impossible to answer. 1. We don't know the goal of the question author (Get the narcissist fired? Rehabilitate them? Make the manager immune to their influence? Deal with the consequences?). 2. We don't have an accurate description of what the problem is. We only know some vague allusion to "weirdest questions" but we don't know what these questions are or what effect they have on the workplace. 3. we don't even know if the person is actually a "narcissist" or if that's just some general slur to discredit someone the author doesn't like.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the misfortune to have several narcissists in both my personal and professional life over the years, and by far the best way I've found to deal with them is **do not engage them.**

Don't argue with them, don't highlight what they're doing (even/especially when they're misrepresenting things), don't talk to them except when strictly necessary (and not even then if you can help it), don't try to beat them at their own game, *just don't engage them*.

If you engage them then they have power, if you don't then they have none.

Do your job, do it well, and leave them out of it as much as possible.

Comment: In general I agree. However someone like that can be offended by you by just doing a better job than them & sabotage you for it. So depending on your relationship with you boss, I might be inclined, after you boss next asks some weird questions, to ask them (off line and in private): It **seems** that **often** after you meet with XYZ you have some odd out of character/context questions. How do you navigate if someone is playing office politics or just need to clarify things with someone? (Note you only make observations 'It seems', and ask 'How' questions. You don't need to elaborate further.